# Passing Vars into an error or response?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using my codeigniter success message for this question.  I would like it to echo out the `$firstname` that is being passed through but I am unsure of the correct syntax I have tried the following:

`$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Thank&#39;s .'$firstname.' please check your email for confirmation');`

but the above gives me the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Comment: Check where you put your period.

Comment: @luxun: is it the period or the quote which is at the wrong place? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Misplaced quote at `'Thank&#39;s .'$firstname.'`. Corrected below:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Thank&#39;s ' . $firstname . ' please check your email for confirmation');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax has an error: 
Try this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Thank&#39;s '.$firstname.' please check your email for confirmation');
```